# How to store Key-Value collections in Java Android?

Tags: java, android

The application needs to store several immutable Key-Value collections

Example

```
{
    1: "Apple",
    2: "LG",
    3: "Samsung"
...
}
```

Collections won't be programmatically modified, and there aren't many of them.  How to store this collection?  And how to use them in a dropdown list (Spinner) for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Map as a data structure for keys and values.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

However, if you want to convert the already written JSON format to Object, consider using a library like Jackson or JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of HashMap you can store the key and value pair as

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>()
```